# How to fail Elasticsearch searches when cluster is in a red state to avoid incomplete results?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have Elasticsearch cluster with multiple nodes and only primary shards, no replicas. As ES documents state, if some primary shards are missing cluster health will become red, indexing will fail, but searches will return partial data. I am using a client node to talk with the cluster. Is there any way to demand from ES to return complete data OR tell me that something went wrong? I guess checking the health before searching, can be a solution, but it will introduce race condition itself and will have a performance penalty.

Any proven solution for such cases?

Comment: Did you restart the cluster?

Comment: @eliasah I did restart the cluster when noticed this behavior, but I guess it can happen without restarting, if I randomly lose some nodes.

Comment: are you monitoring your cluster? if so, what did it tell you?

Comment: @eliasah Unfortunately I was not monitoring my cluster when this happened. In 'this' I mean returning incomplete results. But from ES docs, it seems the Red state can be an issue and during restart it is quite expectable.

Comment: You don't even have marvel installed? It usually comes shipped with ES.

Comment: I have Kopf, but didn't use it. I don't understand what you are trying to find out. The question is more general, rather than just for this case. How to avoid incomplete results from ES when cluster is Red?

Comment: You can't. If it's red it means it's inaccessible, if it's inaccessible no search on the shards or segments thus no results returned from the shards. Conclusion, partial or no results.

Comment: No result is what I want. Unfortunately it returns partial results and I want to avoid it. Let me make it more clear: I don't want complete results, when cluster is red, I want to know that results are incomplete(throwing exception also works) when they are returned from ES.

Comment: You can't force that unless you check the cluster health on each query before querying it again for results after it returns a health check GREEN

Comment: Even that solution has race condition. If you think there is no better way to do it, just write it as an answer please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find direct way to fail searches, when shards are missing, but Elasticsearch returns number of shards it tried to query and number of shards actually responded. So you can validate response. If you are using Java API, SearchResponse class has these methods:

```
    int totalShards = searchResponse.getTotalShards();
    int successfulShards = searchResponse.getSuccessfulShards();
    int failedShards = searchResponse.getFailedShards();
```

You can check if successfulShards equals or not total shards.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do what you are trying to perform.

If the cluster is red it means it's inaccessible, if it's inaccessible no search on the shards or segments thus no results returned from the shards.

Conclusion, partial or no results.

So you can't force not getting partial results unless you check the cluster health on each query before querying it again for results after it returns a health check GREEN.

Obviously this solution has a race condition like you mentioned in your comment but for now, there is no other way around.